# How to input page number in paginator to load page using Prime faces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i am new to JSF and primefaces.

I have a datatable with paginator and i have to customise paginator .
I have to create an input box and if user enter number ex:1 page 1 should load and for 2 page 2 etc..

Here it is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="dtExposure" var="expo" value="#{expoBean.exposureList}" rowKey="#{expo.key}" reflow="true" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"  
                     widgetVar="expoTable" emptyMessage="No Exposure Data" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" resizableColumns="true" style="border-style:hidden;"
                      selection="#{expoBean.selectedExpos}"  currentPageReportTemplate="{totalPages} pages" 
                    paginatorTemplate="{checkbox} {btn_icons}   {CurrentPageReport}  {RowsPerPageDropdown} {PreviousPageLink} {inputpagenumber} {NextPageLink}"
                     paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="20" rowsPerPageTemplate="20,50,100" >


<f:facet name="{inputpagenumber}" >
                <p:inputText style="width:2.5em;" id="test" onchange="{PF('expoTable').getPaginator().setPage(2);}"/>
</f:facet>
```

when i debug always getting  setPage() : undefined

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably `setPage() : undefined` is just fine. "void" Javascript functions always return undefined. `setPage` doesn't return anything, I assume, so it returns undefined. You can test this yourself if you know Javascript. It could be that you have successfully set the page number but you need to trigger a table update somehow.

Comment: You may get better help if you post a _concise_ reproducible error, the debugging steps you have taken, and the behaviour you are seeing. As is anyone can only guess at the issue.